# virtual ip and real ip ports combination are they unique?

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

I have created virtual IP address and virtual ethernet address.I wanted to know whether combination of these dummy Ip and port ,real Ip and port are they unique or not?

ex:
10.198.105.49:5400 //real ip

10.198.105.22:5400 //dummy ip

My question is, is it possible to access both these ips with same port addresses simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

The two you posted are different IP addresses, so yes, they are different endpoints, so if you have two servers listening on each of the end point, they will work as expected.

If you want one server to server on both address, you can bind to `INADDR_ANY` and port 5400, this way, the server will receive on all the ip addresses of the local machine. If you want to check which endpoint the connection is from, you can call `getsockname` to retrieve it.